# Compare \n with Scanner input

Tags: java, string

I am accepting input as `\n`

using

```
String input = scanner.next();
```

My question is, which `if condition` will check if `input is equal to "\n"`.

I tried

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("\n"))
  System.out.println("Catched It!!");
```

but `Catched It!!` is not printed. Please help.

Comment: try `.endsWith("\n");`

Comment: why do you need to do this? There may be an easier solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm guessing you would like that to be `scanner.nextLine();`?

Comment: @Zhuinden- `scanner.nextLine();` also not working..

Comment: Doesn't scanner use the newline character as a delimiter by default?

Comment: Yeah, that is the default delimiter, so it gets rid of any "\n" occurences present

Comment: @JBires &  user1071777 : I have a String and want to replace dots in it with new line char "\n" which is accepted from scanner input.

Comment: so basically you're replacing all periods in the string with any input from the scanner that the user gives, and \n is not working? If you're only replacing the periods with a new line, then just skip the scanner entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner already uses `\n` as its delimiter, so you don't need to check for the newline, and it also removes the `\n` char for you. If you want to check for an empty string use `""` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that "\n" translates to a newline in java. If you want to check that it's equal to the input, use two backslashes to escape out the single backslash. Ergo

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("\\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `"\n"` is one of Java's [escape characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), the newline character (effectively the enter key). In order to have your program search for the characters "\n" you must use the escape character for the backslash, `"\\"`. Your finished code would be `if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("\\n")`. Oh, and it would be "Caught it" not "Catched it".